# Elasticsearch gem - API call format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I using this [gem](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby) for elasticsearch API
I trying to convert the following curl statement to an equivalent API call

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "size": 100,
  "fields": [
    "@message",
    "@timestamp"
  ],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "@message": "drop"
    }
  }
}'
```

I tried these but not getting intended results

**Elasticsearch API**

```
@esearch = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
@data2 = @esearch.search q: {
                              term:{
                                "@message" => "drop"
                              }
                            },
                            size:'100',
                            fields:'["@message", "@timestamp"]'
```

**Transport API**

```
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new
@data = client.perform_request 'GET', '_search', {
                                                    :size=> 100,
                                                    :query=> {
                                                      :term=> {
                                                        "message"=> "drop"
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      :fields=> [
                                                        '@message',
                                                        '@timestamp'
                                                      ]
                                                    }
                                                  }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap all of those parameters in a `body` element:

```
@data2 = @esearch.search 
    body: {
        query: {term:{"@message" => "drop"}}, 
        size:'100', 
        fields:'["@message", "@timestamp"]
   }
```

Comment: Also, see the documentation and examples at http://rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch/API/Actions#search-instance_method